# VBA - grey out (backcolor) Field 2 when field 1 is not blank, but then reset back color of field 2 when field 1 is backspaced

Tags: vba, ms-access

When I begin typing in Field 1 textbox, Field 2's backcolor should be set to [color]. If i were to backspace all text from Field 1, the back color should be set back to white (all before leaving the field, saving, etc.)

Comment: You should edit your question. What exactly are you asking? What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

you may try this code in your UserForm code pane:

```
Option Explicit

Dim typing As Boolean

Private Sub Field1_Change()
    With Me
        If typing Then
            If Len(.Field1.Text) = 0 Then
                .Field2.BackColor = vbWhite
                typing = False
            End If
        Else
            .Field2.BackColor = vbYellow '<--| change vbYellow to your needed Field2 background color
            typing = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @ChrisRay, did you get through it?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of *user3598756* can be reduced to one line:

```
Private Sub Field1_Change()

    Me!Field2.BackColor = IIf(Me!Field1.Text = "", vbWhite, vbGreen)

End Sub
```